# Confused about output of Base.decode16

Tags: elixir

If I use `Base.decode16!` to decode `666F6F` it equals "foo".

```rb
Base.decode16!("666F6F")
# "foo"
```

... but if I decode this:

```rb
Base.decode16!("666F6F01")
# <<102, 111, 111, 1>>
```

Why when I add `01` to the string to decode does the output become a binary?  Why isn't the output "foo1"?

Comment: You're making an incorrect statement though: you're always getting a binary, not just when you add the `01`. `"strings"` are just binaries; `"foo"` is equivalent to `<<"foo">>` or `<<?f, ?o, ?o>>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

01 is not a "valid" ASCII value (it is not text but a symbol called "SOH").

If you want to get "foo1", you need to give "666F6F31".

31 (49 in decimal) is the ASCII value for the character '1'.

The full ASCII table: http://www.asciitable.com/